# Filter string inside double braces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the below content:

```
{\getval f_{x},f_{1},f_{2},f_{k-1},f_{\k}},
{{f}}
{\getval g_{1},g_{2}}
{\ret  {x}}
```

How I can filter by a regular expression to generate the result as:

```
{\retval f_{x},f_{1},f_{2},f_{k-1},f_{\k}},
{{f}}
{\retval g_{1},g_{2}}
{\ret  {x}}
```

I used:

```
\{[^{]*\{[^{]*\}\}
```

to filter all double brace, but I do not know, how to filter the double brace with specific content, I try

```
\{\\getval[^{]*\{[^{]*\}\}
```

but nothing is founded.
If that is difficult to implement. My situation can be resolved if I can find a regex command that filter and catch any opening parent braces that store 'getval' inside. Please suggest me a sulotion.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use this to find the lines that need modifying:

```
\{\\getval
```

(If you have lines that start with `{\getval`, but should not be modified, your question would need to make that clear and specify how to distinguish lines that should be changed from those that should not).

The reason your regex didn't match anything is that this pattern: `[^{]*\{[^{]*` allows there to be only one left brace inside the element, but the lines you want to match have multiple opening braces.  In addition, your regex required a comma at the end, but only one of the lines you need to match has a comma.

Comment: Thank for your reply,
However, I would like to find and replace whole content which have multiple opening braces like the question, because in my code has many kinds of that one, so regex will be helpful to replace all at one time. The comma is my mistake, I just edited it. Do you have any idea to filter for my situation, multiple bracket inside?